# C++: Why can't I access the Node class using Opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors

Hi I am writing a C++ program using OpenCV. I make sure to include the necessary files:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"
```

Everything using opencv works fine and dandy. But when I refer to Node in the following line:

```
    std::vector<Node> nodeList = forest->getNodes();
```

I get the following error:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'Node'
```

I don't understand why, because it recognizes all the other opencv classes. There is probably a simple explanation for this but I don't see it right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the full name of the node class `cv::ml::DTrees::Node`. and if you want to define a vector with a certain size do this:

```
std::vector<Node> nodeList(forest->getNodes().size());
```